# CSS in MasterPage not carrying through to Content Page

Tags: asp.net, css

I'm very new to ASP.NET and have to confess I'm having great difficulty achieving even the most basic of results.

I am currently having trouble getting CSS formatting to work in my content pages.

My master page is as follows -

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Main.master.cs" Inherits="Master_Main" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <link href="../CSS/Main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <div id="Container">
    <div id="Header">Header Goes Here</div>
    <div id="LeftBar">Left Bar Goes Here</div>  
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>     
    <div id="RightBar">Right Bar Goes Here</div>
    <div id="Footer">Footer Goes Here</div>   
    </div>       
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS stylesheet is referenced in the < head > tag and when in Design view on the master page I can see the formatting is in place.

However, when I create a Content Page based on this master page, none of the CSS formatting follows through.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master/Main.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Pages_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<div>
<p>Content Goes Here</p>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

The source for the Content page references the Master Page correctly I believe, but the formatting is simply not working.  My content page is entirely black and white text down the left hands side of the browser.

I'm sure this will be a simple matter to those who are good at ASP, but like I said, I'm struggling with it at the moment, so any help is much appreciated.

For completeness the CSS file is as follows -

```
*
{
    font-family: Calibri;
}

#Header
{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: Gray;
}

#LeftBar
{
    width: 15%;
    float: left;
    background-color: Lime;
}

#Content
{
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
    background-color: White;
}

#RightBar
{
    width: 15%;
    float: left;
    background-color: Yellow;
}

#Footer
{
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    background-color: Red;
}
```

The CSS formatting does appear on the Master Page when in Design view in VWD, but never in the Content Page.

Comment: What styling are you expecting in the ContentPlaceHolder?

Comment: I'm getting NO styling right across the page, not just in the placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

Known issue (if this is what is happening in this case) with Visual Studio. The way to be sure of applying the correct path is to drag the CSS file from Solution Explorer into the head section of the master page (in design view).